# Running shell script without environment variables in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, environment-variables, shell

Xcode sets variety of environment variables related build when running shell script.
Is there a way to running shell script without setting of those variables?

Comment: Can you clarify what you want?  Is that you want to be able to run the script from outside Xcode when those variables won't be set, but you want to set appropriate values in the script so it behaves similarly to the way it does when run from Xcode?  Or is it that you want to run the script from Xcode but want to have all those environment variables set by Xcode unset?

Comment: @Jonathan Latter one. I got solution, and answered myself. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got a solution.
Use this method in `Run Script Phase` target phase:
https://serverfault.com/questions/176966/how-to-continue-execution-of-shell-script-after-calling-other-shell-script-with/176976#176976

These shell commands run following command ignoring variables in current environment.

```
env -i <command>
exec -c <command>
```

As an example, I used this script:

```
env -i ./makeall.sh
```

This disables all of Xcode's predefined variables, so script does not affected by Xcode configuration, but it's also less useful because we cannot use Xcode paths related build.

So, however, you can pass specific Xcode variable like this script.

```
build()
{
    # Don't know why, however, the environment variable passed to external script even with "env -i".
    env -i ./makeall.sh "${SYMROOT}"
}

build
```